# Applying isotope js affects the css of the div

Tags: jquery, html, css

After applying isotope js to the div section, the library is successfully applied to the elements inside the div and everything works. However, the previous div animation that worked isn't working as expected any more.

Here is the fiddle that worked perfectly before applying isotope js:
URL:https://jsfiddle.net/eugensunic/ttf1wkcn/2/

and here is the fiddle when isotope get's applied and the elements are obviously overwritten with some hidden css:

URL https://jsfiddle.net/eugensunic/so1axnup/10/

Here is the code that I'm using (same for both fiddles):

```
$(this).animate({                            
        position: "relative",
        left: "200px",
        top: "200px",
        zIndex: "55"

    }, 1200, function () {
        $(this).animate({                                
            position: "relative",
            left: "0px",
            top: "0px",
            zIndex: "55"
        });
    });
```

I know that I can hard code this to get to the previous animation (fiddle num.1) but is there a more easier way to solve this and why do the elements deteriorate so much with isotope applied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 things which are disturbing your fiddle:

1. The isotope.js is loaded via HTTP instead of HTTPS. due to this the
   effect is not working. Try doing the same with HTTPS and the
   animation will start working.
2. After the animation, you are setting all the elements to `left:0; top:0; position: absolute;z-index:55px`. Due to this, all the divs are stacking over each other. Try forcing the relative position using `position:relative !important` to keep them side by side. I would also suggest to keep the X * Y
   coordinates of the div clicked and then pass them as arguments into your code.

I have updated the fiddle slightly for it.
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aalok/so1axnup/11/)

Comment: Tnx, altough I was looking for a non hard code solution I think I will have to adjust my elements this way...